# How to stop all running mongo background operations?

Tags: mongodb, macos, unix, terminal

I am getting this error when running tests in node.

```
MongoError: cannot perform operation: a background operation is currently running for ...
```

I need a way to stop all running background operations via the command line.

Answer (score 4):

You need [db.killOp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/). This will kill a list of current operations which you can obtain via [db.currentOp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#db.currentOp) which returns a list of all the current operations.

Comment: I'm looking for a fill `mongo` cli with `--exec` to see this work. :(

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/